# Object型のJSONをパースできない。

Tags: javascript, json, api

http://qiita.com/AKB428/items/64938febfd4dcf6ea698#get-animev1mastercours
こちらのAPIを使用させていただこうと考えているのですが、Javascriptで以下のコードでパースしようとしたところ、エラーが出てしまい失敗しました。
このようなObjectだけのJsonをパースするのはどのようにすればいいのでしょうか。

コード
`JSON.parse(jsonData);`

Comment: `jsonData` の中身はどのようなものですか？

Comment: http://api.moemoe.tokyo/anime/v1/master/cours です。

Comment: 正常にパースできます: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7hQPiS-IiADTUkyQmdjSmI4NWc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: コメント有難うございます。
無事パースできました!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

特に問題なくパースできます

ブラウザーによりJSONオブジェクトが使えなかったり、無かったりするので
そういう場合は別途JSONをパースするライブラリーを使用する必要があります。
http://blog.livedoor.jp/dankogai/archives/51503830.html
http://r36at.blogspot.jp/2013/01/jsonparse-json2.html

```js
var jsondata = '{"4":{"id":4,"year":2014,"cours":4},"5":{"id":5,"year":2015,"cours":1},"6":{"id":6,"year":2015,"cours":2},"1":{"id":1,"year":2014,"cours":1},"2":{"id":2,"year":2014,"cours":2},"7":{"id":7,"year":2015,"cours":3},"3":{"id":3,"year":2014,"cours":3}}';

var x = window.JSON.parse(jsondata);

$.each(x, function(name, val){
  var result =　'[' + name + ']:';
  $.each(val, function(name, val){
    result += ' ' + name + ':' + val;
  });
  $('body').append('<div>' + result + '</div>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```